# Find a value in a range and format a range adjacent to it

Tags: excel, vba, string, find, range

I have a "TO:" value in every second or third row but different columns. I have been trying to find "TO:" in a sheet and fill cells with red color until Column A, backwards. I found a macro and customized it as following. I managed to color "TO:" with red with it, but did not manage to fill color into the cells until Column A. For example if TO is found in L2, fill Red L2:A2 and likewise. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Sub FindAndChangeStyle()

Dim TestPhrases() As String
Dim rng, Rng2 As Range
Dim lastCol, i As Long
TestPhrases = Split("TO:", "KotaPota")
 Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address)


With ActiveSheet
Dim oLookin As Range
   Dim CheckCell As Range
    For Each CheckCell In rng


        Dim Looper As Long
        For Looper = LBound(TestPhrases) To UBound(TestPhrases)

            If InStr(CheckCell.Value, TestPhrases(Looper)) Then
                CheckCell.Font.Bold = True
                CheckCell.Interior.Color = vbRed

                Exit For
            End If


        Next Looper

    Next CheckCell
End With

   End Sub
```

Comment: "KotaPota" is redundant item. I just used it to customize an existing macro in Stalkoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, maybe you can just loop through all cells containing the `"TO:"` substring (using `Range.Find`).

The code below will try to find all case-insensitive, partial matches for the `"TO:"` substring, and make apply some formatting to the cells on that row (starting from column A and ending on the cell containing the substring).

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ColourMatchingCells()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Dim matchFound As Range
        Set matchFound = .Cells.Find("TO:", , xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, xlNext, False) ' This will search all cells (of the sheet). Change as needed. '

        If matchFound Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox ("Could not find a single cell containing the substring. Code will stop running now.")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim addressOfFirstMatch As String
        addressOfFirstMatch = matchFound.Address

        Do
            With .Range(.Cells(matchFound.Row, "A"), matchFound)
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Interior.Color = vbRed
            End With
            Set matchFound = .Cells.FindNext(matchFound)
        Loop Until matchFound.Address = addressOfFirstMatch ' Once you have looped through all matches, you should return to the first one '
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Chillin for the very swift and perfect solution. I tested your code and it works perfectly. Tons of thanks.